# Python NumPy-style documentation of dict

Tags: python, numpy, documentation

Based on [this](http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_numpy.html), a list parameter should be documented like:

```
Parameters
----------
param1 : :obj:`list` of :obj:`str`
```

How would you document a dict parameter?

Related question: Adding the `:obj:` seems to make `list` clickable (intellij doc. preview ~ ctrl+q) however there's no mention of `str` anymore, which seems odd. So is the above convention still correct?

```
Parameters
----------
param1 : list of str
```

Reasoning: trying to keep some standard in my documentation and since I'm using NumPy heavily, would rather stick to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
variable : dict of str
    description
```

will show `Dict[str]` when intellij is set to NumPy doctstring format (Python Integrated Tools)